# Mounting AWS ELB volume, mount point does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I've built a CoreOS Kubernetes (1.0.7) Cluster in AWS and everything seems to work swimmingly, except Volumes.  I manually create a volume in the same zone as my nodes prior to bringing up an RC with the volume configured. As below:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: ReplicationController
 metadata:
   name: jenkins
 spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
     app: jenkins
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: jenkins
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: jenkins
         image: jenkins
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080
         - containerPort: 50000
         volumeMounts:
         - name: "jenkins-data"
           mountPath: "/var/jenkins_home"
         livenessProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /
             port: 8080
           initialDelaySeconds: 60
           timeoutSeconds: 180
       volumes:
       - name: "jenkins-data"
         awsElasticBlockStore:
           volumeID: aws://us-east-1c/vol-abcd123
           fsType: ext4
```

The pod begins to come up, but waits for the volume to mount.  The volume properly attaches to the instance (I see it in `fdisk`) but is unable to be mounted properly when I turn up logging on the kublet:

```
 safe_format_and_mount[1504]: Running: fsck.ext4 -a /dev/xvdf
 safe_format_and_mount[1508]: /dev/xvdf: clean, 11/655360 files, 79663/2621440 blocks
 safe_format_and_mount[1513]: Running: mount -o discard,defaults /dev/xvdf /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1c/vol-abcd123
 safe_format_and_mount[1516]: mount: mount point /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1c/vol-abcd123 does not exist
 safe_format_and_mount[1519]: Disk /dev/xvdf looks formatted but won't mount.  Giving up.
```

Now that error is correct, the `/var/lib/kubelet/plugins` dir exists but is empty from there out.  Seems like I'm missing something here that should be creating this directory?  I've looked around previous issues and seen many regarding safe_format_and_mount but haven't seen any regarding that directory.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is strange - the code clearly call mkdir if it doesn't exist...

Can you run `find /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/` for me?

Comment: @TimHockin Sure, thank you!

     `$ find /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/` : 
    `/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/ `

Comment: @TimHockin Unfortunately nothing there on the node.

Comment: Are there any related logs from above in the kubelet? Tim's right: Kubelet calling safe_format_and_mount on a nonexistent target dir shouldn't happen... https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.0.7/pkg/volume/aws_ebs/aws_util.go#L67